# How to iterate object when it contains array of objects?

Tags: arrays, object, mule, mulesoft

**Input** :

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "address": [{
        "street": "5",
        "city": "ameerpet",
        "pin": "500073"
    }, {
        "street": "6",
        "city": "sec",
        "pin": "500020"
    }]
}
```

Note: ["LAA001","LAA002","LAA003"] -> use this as a variable

**Required output**:

```
[{
        "id": "123",
        "lob": "LAA001",
        "attributeText": "5"
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "lob": "LAA001",
        "attributeText": "6"
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "lob": "LAA002",
        "attributeText": "ameerpet"
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "lob": "LAA002",
        "attributeText": "sec"
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "lob": "LAA003",
        "attributeText": "500073"
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "lob": "LAA003",
        "attributeText": "500020"
    }
]
```

Comment: The correlation between input and the expected output is hard to ascertain without any information from your side. You would need to explain as to how you are trying to derive the output from the given input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, that should work:

```js
var input = { "id": "123", "address": [ { "street": "5", "city": "ameerpet", "pin": "500073" }, { "street": "6", "city": "sec", "pin": "500020" }] }
    var iob = ["LAA001","LAA002","LAA003"]
    var output = []
    
    input['address'].forEach((item, index) => {
      var keyIndex = 0 
      for(const key in item){
        let obj = {
          "id": input['id'],
          "lob": iob[keyIndex],
          "attributeText": item[key]
        }
        output.push(obj)
        keyIndex += 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inp = ["LAA001","LAA002","LAA003"]
var inp1 = payload.address.street ++ payload.address.city ++ payload.address.pin
---
inp1 map {
   id: payload.id,
   lob: inp[(($$)/2)],
   attributeText: $
}
```